# passive voice misuse by Grammarly

Tags: passive-voice

why is Grammarly showing passive voice misuse in the following sentence"All steps that decrease cost is accepted in the standard algorithm." and showing "All steps that decrease cost gets accepted in the standard algorithm." as correct.

Comment: Neither of those sentences is correct—and it has nothing to do with the passive voice.

Answer (score 1):

They are both wrong. The subject is "All steps" so the verb should be in plural form:

> All steps that decrease cost are accepted in the standard algorithm

Same for

> All steps that decrease cost get accepted in the standard algorithm

You might want to change it to

> All steps that decrease cost are accepted by the standard algorithm

meaning that the algorithm accepts all steps that are decreasing, if the algorithm is specifically designed to accept those steps and the acceptance is not just a part of a larger algorithm.

Comment: "All steps that decrease cost are accepted by the standard algorithm."..still showing passive voice misuse??

Comment: Try "All steps are accepted by the standard algorithm", maybe grammarly gets confused by the relative clause.

Comment: All steps are accepted by the standard algorithm...still showing passive voice misuse??.. I think Grammarly is not letting me use "are" with past tense form "accepted"....but not able to understand why??

Comment: @PRABHANSHU "Grammarly" is an app. Don't let it control you. The sentence "All steps that decrease cost are accepted by the standard algorithm" is fine. Grammarly, like Microsoft Word, despises passive voice.